# Speaker Recognition and Response Time?

Tags: azure, speaker

I know that Speaker Recognition is in preview and the only available location is the West Coast, and Im hoping that's why I am seeing this 'delay'.

Im on the East Coast (NY) and with just 3 speakers in my search it takes 6 seconds to return a confirmation.  Dont get me wrong, 6 seconds is impressive for what it does but that long of delay makes the use case more limited than a quicker reply.

Main question is - Should I see a quicker reply once the service adds location closer?   (Its not like the latency should cause a big issue...) - Or is there anything else that may speed up replies - or, of course, is this simply 'The way its going to be'??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about [Microsoft Speaker Recognition](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speaker-recognition-api).

The processing time is a function of the audio length. For a 15 seconds audio, you can expect less than 1 second latency, and yes, in general, you should see quicker response when the service expands to closer locations.